# Wireshark and Playstation 3

Tags: wireshark

I'm looking to capture all network traffic when playing my ps3 and find the external IP addresses of other players in my servers or game. I'm wondering if this is possible?  If so how?

Comment: Is this so you can "DoS" the competitors when they make you mad?

Comment: Not clear on what you are looking for. If you're looking to monitor traffic on locally hosted game that doesn't go through PSN that's possible as it's your network. However, if you aren't hosting the game and/or if PSN is required than this would violate Sony's ToS because it's their network.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to buy a hub, not a switch, for your PS3 and run wireshark on a computer attached to the hub.  The other option is to run a mirror port from a switch to your computer, if your switch supports it.

Lastly, if you have a fairly decent firewall you can just log all connections or sessions, this would give the IP's but not necessarily the packet decodes.

I suppose if you made your computer the Internet router for your PS3 you can also capture from that.  Basically allow forwarding on you computer, have your PS3 on one side and the Internet on the other then do a capture.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Does this also apply to packet sniffing over WiFi?

Answer (score 1):

Since every user connect to the Playstation Network, this seems unlikely to be possible. It's like asking to capture an IP address of a user on Stack Exchange.

Comment: This is plain wrong, there are plenty of P2P-based games which are hosted on locally, so there's no reason you wouldn't be able to determine the IP of whoever is connected to you if you are the host.

Answer (score 0):

Before reading this answer, I should make you aware that DDoS and any other type of network attack are criminal offenses and I hope you do not use this knowledge towards that goal.

You could set up a simple proxy on a computer that receives the traffic on your public ip on the playstation port using port forwarding, and then forwards all traffic to an internal ip (your Playstation) on the same port. You could then log this traffic using Wireshark. I'm pretty sure that Playstation is not all peer to peer, though (correct me if I'm wrong!)

Hope it helps and I hope you don't misuse this information..

Comment: Welcome, and thanks for trying to help with this question.  Two comments.  First, this site compiles questions and answers for future reference so it is important that answers be definitive and reliable.  You should be sure of what you answer.  If not, look it up before answering.  Second, describing a general approach is usually not a good answer.  If the reader already knows how to implement it, they probably know your answer.  Provide some specific information on how to accomplish the task.